# how to render a float to 2 spaces only if it is less than 1

Tags: objective-c, ios

in iOS I have a distance selector that is:

```
  0.25 miles
  1.00 miles
  3.00 miles
```

and is rendered out as:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f miles", [i floatValue]];
```

How would i just render:

```
0.25
1 
3
```

thx

Answer (score 2):

You mean, **if** it is less than one, do something else?

```
if ([i floatValue]<1) {
   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f miles", [i floatValue]];
}
else {
   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f miles", [i floatValue]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `NSNumberFormatter`. A short example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
double d1 = 0.25;
double d2 = 1.00;
double d3 = 3.00;
NSLog(@"d1: %@\nd2: %@\nd3: %@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d1]], [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d2]], [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d3]]);
```

output:

```
2012-05-16 07:50:17.153 testApp[266:207] d1: 0,25
d2: 1
d3: 3
```

Hope it helps